# OxyPlot strange series

Tags: c#, oxyplot

How can I draw something like this:

[image]

What type of series would I need to use?

Comment: Did you get that image from some source or did you draw it yourself in paint. If it is from some source, look at how they did it. If they are not using OxyPlot, you will have to try to create a specific custome series kind in OxyPlot to mimic this, and come back here if you have tried, got stuck and have a more specific question than this one.

Answer (score 0):

That's an [open-high-low-close (OHLC) chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart). It's frequently used with financial data like stock prices. In that context, a stock has an opening and closing price at the start and end of a time period, and also a highest price and lowest price during that period. The vertical bar is the highest and lowest value for the time period; the horizontal bar on the left is the open, and the bar on the right is the close.

OxyPlot doesn't appear to have an OHLC series, but the [candlestick series](http://oxyplot.org/documentation/series/CandleStickSeries) is a similar method of displaying OHLC data.